# Downloaded svg file unable to be filled

Tags: file, svg, browser

I've downloaded this icon in svg format from [thenounproject](https://thenounproject.com/icon/home-4688386/).

I opened it in VS Code, and could successfully remove the advertising text. That left me with this code:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 100 125" x="0px" y="0px">
<path d="M76.25,87.5h-15a3.75,3.75,0,0,1-3.75-3.75V61.25h-15v22.5a3.75,3.75,0,0,1-3.75,3.75h-15A11.263,11.263,0,0,1,12.5,76.25V46A14.9,14.9,0,0,1,18.291,34.16l24.8-19.29a11.244,11.244,0,0,1,13.814,0l24.8,19.291A14.9,14.9,0,0,1,87.5,46V76.25A11.263,11.263,0,0,1,76.25,87.5ZM65,80H76.25A3.754,3.754,0,0,0,80,76.25V46a7.45,7.45,0,0,0-2.895-5.92L52.3,20.79a3.749,3.749,0,0,0-4.606,0L22.9,40.08h0A7.45,7.45,0,0,0,20,46V76.25A3.754,3.754,0,0,0,23.75,80H35V61.25a7.509,7.509,0,0,1,7.5-7.5h15a7.509,7.509,0,0,1,7.5,7.5ZM20.593,37.12h0Z"/>
</svg>
```

However, the inside of the svg icon is still empty, so I wanted to fill it by writing `fill="black"` at the end of `<path/>`. But when I do that, nothing changes. I tried opening the svg in MS Edge and Firefox, and the inside was still empty.

Does anybody have a clue why it's not filled?

Comment: It is filled though, the inside is the black bit because the shape traces one line inside another.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. Is there any way to make the white part inside the lines black, then?

Comment: Sure, edit the path so it's what you want it to be. You can use an SVG editor such as Inkscape if you're not sure what to do directly.

Comment: For a single ``d`` path, this online editor is easier: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after about 10 mins, I removed all the nodes from the inner lines, giving me a completely black shape and thus what I wanted.

[image]

Comment: please show the resulting SVG content at least.

Comment: Added an image of the result